# Mathematical Formulations for Google-OR tools

Tags: or-tools

I recently started looking into Google-OR tools. However, I do not see mathematical formulations of any of the problems the OR-tools can solve. Without looking at the model (set, objective, constraints, etc), it is hard for me to understand the problem. Does anyone know where I can find them? If you used it for your work, how did you use the tools?

Comment: have you looked at examples ?

Comment: I was looking for the mathematical formulation with math notations.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://developers.google.com/optimization/examples) includes all the codes for the instances that are written to be used in the Google-Or tool. Variety of languages such as C++, Python, DotNet and Java are used to write the codes and solve the instances using Google-OR tool.

Comment: I saw that but I was looking for models described in the usual OR way, like defining sets, indices, parameter, objective function, and constraints with mathematical notations. For example: here is an example of a Technician routing problem in Gurobi. The model  was described first mathematically. https://gurobi.github.io/modeling-examples/technician_routing_scheduling/technician_routing_scheduling.html

Comment: @mars I see what you mean. I sent a request to the Google OR tools developers to consider adding the mathematical versions of their model into their github and website.

Comment: This will not happen. Too much work, a lot of problem do no have a simple mathematical formulation. The code is much more compact than a mathematical formulation, especially in python And it is too much work. If I have spare time, which I do not, I would rather add another example.

Comment: @LaurentPerron, worth noting that you are an OR dev at Google (per your profile), so your comment is more than anecdotal