# Google OR-Tools, algorithms under the hood?

Tags: or-tools

Under the hood, what algorithms does Google OR-tools support?

From adjacent questions, I saw someone as this [question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/mathematical-formulations-for-google-or-tools) and the answer linked to this [repo](https://developers.google.com/optimization/examples). However, these sources just show how to use Google OR-tools to solve problems, not explain something akin to "we support Ant Colony optimization for problems A, B and C."

I really have no idea if, on the backend, OR-tools is using established heuristic algorithms or if the developers introduced some/many novel algorithms that don't appear elsewhere in literature and/or popular solvers.

Answer (score 4):

This was asked and replied multiple times

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954890/what-approximate-tsp-algorithm-does-google-or-tools-use

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123397/which-solver-do-googles-or-tools-modules-for-csp-and-vrp-use/57125734#57125734

Also: https://github.com/or-tools/awesome_or-tools